# What do you call someone who exploits people and their confidence using ‘clever speech’?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

I am referring to someone who makes people ‘buy’ what he says and gets things done by them through *nothing but clever speech* – something one can describe as *crafty* or *beguiling*, but not *fraudulent*.

I pondered over *con man* and *con artist* for a while but those terms seem to hold a hint of crime, so those terms won’t fit in.

I am wondering if there is a more suitable phrase or word.

Comment: What you describe sounds like your typical *salesman* to me!

Comment: The first word that came to mind was "slick". Also applicable might be "smooth operator" (both words, together or separate).

Comment: I'm  little confused since you ask about someone who *exploits* but don't want connotations of *crime* or *fraud*.

Comment: @Jim - Not all forms of exploitation are criminal or fraudulent in the legal sense, regardless of the moral implications. For instance, someone could exploit a "friend" by having them buy their lunch every day (through unscrupulous means of persuasion). This is neither criminal, nor fraudulent, but it would be valid to say that this person is exploiting their so called friend.

Comment: @Jim I agree you. This is why: "Exploitation" is not necessarily  a criminal offense, as Alexander said. Yet the connotation is very, very strong. Given that fact, and that this is EL&U, I really don't agree with answers such as "eloquence". However, most of the answers strike the perfect note, with words and phrases heavily suggestive of disrepute and deceit, which (in this case) I think is great!

Comment: Sounds like Manipulative (adj) or manipulator (noun) fits the bill.

Comment: A `politician` maybe ?

Comment: A cunning linguist?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Sophistry](https://www.google.com/search?q=definition+sophistry) is crafty speech intended to deceive, not necessarily out and out lying. So then a

> **[sophist](https://www.google.com/search?q=definition+sophist)**

is someone who does it. This is mostly just to win arguments though, not necessarily to get people to do things. That would be a **[demagogue](https://www.google.com/search?q=definition+demagogue)**, but that is someone, yes, who is clever with words but in a very specific way, appealing to the listener's baser instincts.

Comment: Oh good one! So the noun would be *sophist* right?

Comment: @KitFox:  Oh. Right. Yes.

Comment: I don't think sophist is appropriate at all. From OED – Specious but fallacious reasoning; employment of arguments which are intentionally deceptive. The OP specifically asked for non-deception words.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: so are you saying that 'eloquence' is 'exploitative'?

Comment: @Mitch I think it's closer to what he's looking for than Sophist to be honest. But given that your answer has 3 upvotes and mine one downvote suggests not many people agree, but I think that says more about the people who populate this site and what titillates them than what word is closest to what the OP is actually looking for. My interpretation of what he wants is a smooth talker, a sophist produces spurious intellectual arguments for the sake of it. Two quite different beasts, hence my original comment.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: I don't see why yours was downvoted, but 'eloquence' has too much positivity associated with it to be consistent with all the negative words the OP uses.

Comment: You're probably right. I don't think it's entirely clear precisely what word the OP is looking for, hence the fairly wide variety of answers. As has been said many times on SE, the quality of the question dictates the quality of the answer. Downvotes don't really concern me as frequently they come from users who don't understand the question themselves.

Comment: You missed *casuist*.

Comment: This is certainly the best answer, for it is a good metaphoric noun, which is what the OP was seeking (as opposed to the other adjectival suggestions), and is better than "snake oil salesman" in brevity and truth.

Comment: While most answers seem to suggest at least one very closely related term for what I am looking for, I think ___sophist___ (defined by ODO as _a person who reasons with clever but false arguments_) is the nearest. Also, I found quite a bit of text on the Corpus of Contemporary American English with the word _sophistry_, such as "...but that was _sophistry_ and she knew it", "cheap _sophystry_", "... the _sophistry_ here masks a deeper issue", "... almost confounded by his _sophistry_" and much more. So for now, I will go with ___sophist___. Thanks everyone.

Comment: would calling Hitler a "sophist" be correct ?

Comment: @RitwikG: I don't think Hitler was out to just win an argument (which is what sophistry is usually about). I think 'demagogue' really did fit at some point.

Comment: @Mitch: When my boss explains to us why he can't raise our salaries this year and that somehow sounds convincing despite holding no truth in it, I think that is _sohphistry_. I believe Hitler followed similar tactics in convincing Germans that he was their saviour. But yes, I agree with you, that can't be called _sophistry_.

Answer (score 26):

Not quite a single word, but [***silver tongued***](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/silver%2Btongue) probably fits.

Comment: You could hyphenate it.

Comment: Would that count as one word, though? Not sure...

Comment: @AndrewLeach The one-word question is something of a wild red-herring–chase. Yes, a ***silver-tongued* devil** has a one-word modifier in front of *devil*. But any distinction between “one word”, “one-word”, and “oneword” is purely typographic convention, not one of speech, and therefore not one of language. All are just as much of a term as the others. All can occur as headwords in any dictionary worthy of the name, and all should be be matched by a search for the others under most circumstances.

Comment: FWIW, most dictionaries I checked listed the noun _silver tongue_ without a hyphen, and the adjective _silver-tongued_ with a hyphen. Also, to echo what @tchrist said, when such expressions exist as their own entry in the dictionary, I've always considered that a legitimate answer to a single-word request, be it [with](http://www.onelook.com/?w=silver+tongued) or [without](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/silver-tongue) the hyphen.

Answer (score 22):

A ***"Snake oil salesman"*** is someone who uses speech to get people to believe something through their words alone and not through any empirical evidence.

Or...

***"Wheedler"*** - from ["wheedle"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?word=wheedle):

> v. whee·dled, whee·dling, whee·dles
> v.tr.
>
> 1. To persuade or attempt to persuade by flattery or guile; cajole.
> 2. To obtain through the use of flattery or guile: a swindler who wheedled my life savings out of me.
>
> v.intr.
>
> To use flattery or cajolery to achieve one's ends.

Comment: +1 'Snake oil salesman' was the term that immediately came to mind.

Comment: I can't add my own answer -- but **cozener** would also be very appropriate.  [Cozen](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cozen) can mean `to deceive, win over, or induce to do something by artful coaxing and wheedling or shrewd trickery`, which is exactly what the OP had in mind.  Certainly by that particular definition it is closer than wheedler.

Comment: I like *cajole* I think that's a pretty close match to what the OP is looking for. Plus you're so close to 3k I'll +1 you :)

Comment: Thanks! I love looming milestones!  3K before 2013? We'll see! (Still 5 hours away here!)

Answer (score 6):

[**Glib**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/glib): fluent and easy, often in an insincere or deceptive way, artfully persuasive in speech; "a glib tongue"; "a smooth-tongued hypocrite".

Answer (score 5):

This kind of person sounds like a [charismatic authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charismatic_authority)—someone who holds power through a [cult of personality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cult_of_personality).

Answer (score 3):

The word that springs to mind for me is [hawker](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hawker)

- One who sells goods aggressively, especially by calling out.
- (Business / Commerce) a person who travels from place to place selling goods

also, but archaic, would be a [crier](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crier), but that word is now taken as the first two definitions, and the 3rd definition is vary rarely used

Answer (score 2):

One or another of these should do you:

- articulate
- persuasive
- well-worded
- well-spoken
- eloquent
- convincing
- compelling
- unctuous
- slimy
- smooth
- winning
- enticing
- alluring
- beguiling
- cajoling
- seductive
- inveigling
- ensnaring
- bewitching
- enchanting

There’s a lot more where that came from.  But I do like the aforementioned *silver-tongued*.

Answer (score 2):

I would call somebody who can *talk their way out of situations* or *manipulate people just with clever speech* as a **smooth talker** or **smooth operator** colloquially speaking.

According to [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=smooth%20operator) a **Smooth Operator** is

> 1. A person who can ease their way through things, typically using words. Also may be a player. It seems this person may have a way with
>      words and always knows what to say.
> 2. They may also be cunning, wily, and might be willing to lie, cheat, or steal to get what they want.

It has good and bad connotation, it all depends on how it's used.

A more formal word to use would be **suave**. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suave) defines it as

> smoothly though often superficially gracious and sophisticated

Answer (score 1):

*Wheeler-Dealer* (like Del Boy in *Only Fools and Horses*).

Comment: Please cite at least one reliable source.

Answer (score 1):

The word [charmer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/charmer) in sometimes used in this context – at least in British English, where we would also refer as someone with such oratory prowess as being able to [charm the birds from the trees](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=972442).

Answer (score 0):

*Eloquence* might fit.

From Oxford English Dictionary (OED) –

> Eloquence
>
> The action, practice, or art of expressing thought with fluency, force, and appropriateness, so as to appeal to the reason or move the feelings. Also concr. eloquent language.

Comment: "Eloquence" does not imply deception.

Comment: @aearon He's not asking for a word that *implies deception* he's asking for a word that implies *persuasion without deception*.

Comment: He's asking for the name for a person who..., in otherwords, a noun. (btw, I'm not the downvoter)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could go the simple route:

> **[trickster](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trickster)**
>   1. One that swindles or plays tricks.
>   2. often *Trickster* A mischievous or roguish figure in myth or folklore, often an animal, who typically makes up for physical weakness with cunning and subversive humor.

Note that the tricks involved are normally, though not exclusively, verbal in nature.

Answer (score 0):

How about some or all of

perfidious, treacherous, dishonest, false, corrupt, deceitful, untrustworthy, traitorous, two-faced, recreant, a snake

Answer (score 0):

A *rhetorician* is a rhetoric expert: an expert at persuading people with speech.

See the “rhetorician” entry at *OneLook.com* for definitions and synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

If you seek a definition with some connection to cult of personality I'd suggest "Svengali" and "Mesmerist." A bit obscure but they also provide some panache. It's also fun to make people look things up.