# Uncommonly used words. Not popular

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I am trying to recall a word describing or rather defining a person who is extremely clever in speech; overly intelligent and often intentionally misleading or as not to directly address something in particular when speaking. It begins with the letter R and refers to a female person (generally).

Comment: Articulate....?

Comment: disingenuous? sophistical? revanchiste?

Comment: This thread includes many, many possibilities. It's worth reading all the way to the end: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96154/what-do-you-call-someone-who-exploits-people-and-their-confidence-using-clever

Comment: "Gave you the *runaround*" ? *rhetorician* ? *rigmarole* ?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be **roundaboutarian**? *Roundaboutation* is a very old-fashioned, humorous term for *circumlocution* ([Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/roundaboutation)), which is

> The use of many words where fewer would do, especially in a deliberate
>   attempt to be vague or evasive ([Oxford Dictionaries, circumlocution](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/circumlocution))

As for generally applying to women, I've primarily encountered *roundaboutation* in Regency romance novels ([this blogger](http://everything2.com/title/Roundaboutation) notes the same phenomenon), so mainly used *by* women, and there is at least [one reference to a (possibly fictitious) women's society called the Roundaboutarians](http://m.thenorthfieldnews.com/news/2015-04-09/Entertainment/Silly_Social_Scenes.html#.V5zvactOlnE), possibly a play on *Rotarians*.